# Toggling a class and audio and saving it using localstorage

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage

**The problem I'm trying to solve:**
On my website I'm trying to build a way for the user to change the volume to on/off and save it across different pages. So when the user goes to index.html and about.html, I want the setting saved.

**My thinking:**
I am currently trying to solve this by saving the class `active` to localstorage and adding that to the button `#MyElement` that I use to toggle the audio. Then the `.active` class on the `#MyElement` button determines if audio will be played or not.

Furthermore I have javascript to play the audio file when I hover over the `.box` divs (1 and 2 in the codepen). This part seems to be working as I want it, however: when the page loads (I refresh the page and the previous setting was `.active`, the audio doesn't play! Then I need to toggle it again to `.active` and only then will it play. It seems like this piece of code doesn't recognise the other part.

How do I make sure the audio part listens to the localstorage class that is saved? I believe my code also uses part jQuery and part native javascript. I am quite new to this and mostly try to learn from other code snippets and slowly implementing things, however I'm stuck on this now for some time.

```
// Playing audio based on .active

document.querySelectorAll("[data-sound]").forEach(function (element) {
  // Play associated audio
  element.addEventListener("mouseenter", function (event) {
    // element = $("body");'
    if ($("#MyElement").is(".active")) var soundKey = element.dataset.sound;
    var audioElement = document.querySelector("#" + soundKey);

    if (!audioElement) return;

    audioElement.currentTime = 0;
    audioElement.play();
  });
});

// Saving classes to localstorage

$("#MyElement").addClass(localStorage.getItem("ClassName"));

$("#MyElement").on("click", function () {
  if ($(this).hasClass("active")) {
    $(this).removeClass("active").addClass("inactive");
    localStorage.setItem("ClassName", "inactive");
  } else {
    $(this).removeClass("inactive").addClass("active");
    localStorage.setItem("ClassName", "active");
  }
});
```

https://codepen.io/lucvanloon/pen/LYNLeEw

Thank you for taking a look!
Luc

Answer (score 0):

Create a `sessionStorage` as follows:

```
sessionStorage.setItem("audio", "active");

document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = sessionStorage.getItem("audio");
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out that the codepen isn't working because of policy in Google Chrome: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes

It's not allowed to autoplay audio. Regardless if I save a previous user setting or not, it's always reset when the page refreshes.